# since avr-libc 2.0 I have problems process direct char arrays

Tags: c, eclipse, arduino, avr

I use WinAVR with eclipse to program an Arduino (AVR ATmega 328p). Since I updated the AVR-LibC to 2.0 I am not able to process direct char-arrays (Strings).
When I try 
`char test[10] = "hallo";
RS232_SendString(test);`
it works and sends (68 61 6C 6C ...), but when i try

`RS232_SendString("hallo");`
it just sends nothing (00 00 00 00 ...).

Does anyone knows whats the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Spider

Comment: Making an educated guess, I'd would say that you're not initializing the memory location where your string literals are stored. (This should be done before `main`, but normally shouldn't be your job, so this might be a bug - though unlikely - in avr-libc). The array (probably on the stack) might get initialized with direct compiler generated constant values, and not the literal.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for responding. Well, I actually don't know where the error was, but I fixed it by creating a new C Project and copied all my source to the new project. So it was any of the compiler setting..